# Applying multiple CIFilters on image

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a problem with adding multiple CIFilters on image, f.e. when I add brightness filter and then try to add contrast image goes to original (losses brightness filter) and then adds contrast filter.

```
- (IBAction)brightnessSlider:(NSSlider*)sender {
    ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)[NSApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.contentViewController;
    CIFilter *brightness = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, originalCIImage, @"inputBrightness", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[sender floatValue]], nil];
    controller.imageView.image = [self fromCIImageToNSImage:[brightness outputImage]];
}

- (IBAction)contrastSlider:(id)sender {
    ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)[NSApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.contentViewController;
    CIFilter *contrast = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, originalCIImage, @"inputContrast", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[sender floatValue]], nil];
    controller.imageView.image = [self fromCIImageToNSImage:[contrast outputImage]];
}
```

If I use `originalCIImage = [CIFilter outputImage];` (CIFilter = brightness/contrast) after adding brightness and contrast (applying filters for changed image), then the image goes completely black/grey/white.

**How to prevent image from changing back to original and apply several filters simultaneously?**

I have read this post answer [link of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938562/how-to-change-brightness-contrast-and-saturation-using-cicolorcontrols-via-uisl) but applying filters to original image just resets the image as it should..

Comment: Where does originalCIImage come from?

Comment: I overload `windowDidLoad` in my WindowToolbarController and there I take image from ImageView which is in ViewController. Just like this: `originalCIImage = [self fromNSImageToCIImage:((ViewController*)[NSApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.contentViewController).imageView.image];`. Function fromNSIimgToCImg works like this NSImage > CGImage > CIImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I came in with a solution for this each time slider is used I applied **all the filters in each slider**. (Let's say I have brightness and contrast slider).

F.e.: 1) when contrast slider is used I apply brightness and contrast filter on image and save the contrast slider value.

2) when brightness slider is used I apply contrast (with saved value) filter and then brightness filter and save brightness slider value.

3) etc.

Hope someone will get this useful!

Comment: did you find any much more efficient method?
considering the case of applying tens of pre filter just for one filter.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is applying one filter to the original image if you click the first button, and applying a different filter to the original image if you click the other button.

If you want to apply 2 filters, you need to write code that takes the original image, feeds it into the input of the first filter, sets the other parameters, then gets the output into another CIImage.

Then you need to feed the output of the first filter in as the input of the second filter, set those parameters, etc.

Lather, rinse, repeat for as many filters as you want.

See this link for working example code in Swift: https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/core-image-intro/

Comment: I have checked the link, it shows how to add 2 filters, as you said - taking 1st filter output and feeding it to 2nd filter. I do the same thing, after adding a filter I assign it's output to global CIImage variable to save it and then I use it afterwards as input to other filters. The image just goes completely white/grey/black. **BUT** if I add "SepiaTone" filter on top, using exactly the same code it works just fine as described. I am so frustrated, I have no idea why exact the same code doesn't work on "ColorControls" filters.